# Are there any visual indicators that tell a player they are about to earn Experience Points?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There seem to be an inordinate number of ways to earn experience including reading data logs, finding medi-gel, pacifying enemies, dialogue options, etc.

Is there anyway to know whether or not an interaction will award you experience before you choose to interact with an object/person?

Comment: I don't understand how earning experience is at all related to precluding missions.  Seems like you "expanded" on your question with a completely different question.

Comment: @bwarner Good point. It is sort of 2 questions both phrased fairly poorly at the moment...

Comment: It is a generally bad idea to lump questions together on SE. I do believe the second question is already being discussed somewhere on the site, probably best for you to just delete it and focus on the first question.

Comment: If you're supposed to do it, it will give you XP. Anything you do for a mission (even walking through a door) might give you XP.

Comment: -1 due to convoluted thought organization and block o' text problem.

Comment: I have split the question into two questions (the way it should have been presented in the first place). Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no indicators of any sort to tell you whether an action will give you experience. Experience is generally awarded for completing mission objectives, collecting surplus medi-gel and reading journals.

You will often be precluded from returning to areas after completing an objective. Doors will also often become permanently locked after a cutscene plays during a mission. It is a good idea to thoroughly explore an area before moving on with the quest after the enemies have been cleared out, if you wish to obtain the most items and credits.

Answer (score -1):

You could always use a strategy guide, but you'll definitely be spoiled in a lot of places if you do.  It's just a matter of developers trying to make games as realistic and branching as possible -within reason.

You get experience in pretty much everything you do.  If you could see the future you would probably do things differently.  It's the same in video games.  But there's no way that you can see the future and not have the drama of the action spoiled.  That's just the decision you'll have to make.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mass-Effect-Collectors-Prima-Official/dp/030789150X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/030789150X)